# Calculate 2^(n) where 0<n<10000

Tags: c#, algorithm

So, this is my problem to solve:

I want to calculate 2^(n) where   0 < n< 10000

I am representing each element of array as a space where 4digit number should be "living" and if extra digit appears, I am replacing it to the next element of this array.

The principle I am using looks like this:

[image]

The code I am using is the following:

```
static string NotEfficient(int power)
{
    if (power < 0)
        throw new Exception("Power shouldn't be negative");
    if (power == 0)
        return "1";
    if (power == 1)
        return "2";

    int[] A = new int[3750];

    int current4Digit = 0;

    //at first 2 is written in first element of array
    A[current4Digit] = 2;

    int currentPower = 1;

    while (currentPower < power)
    {
        //multiply every 4digit by 2
        for (int i = 0; i <= current4Digit; i++)
        {
            A[i] *= 2;
        }

        currentPower++;

        //checking every 4digit if it
        //contains 5 digit and if yes remove and 
        //put it in next 4digit
        for (int i = 0; i <= current4Digit; i++)
        {
            if (A[i] / 10000 > 0)
            {
                int more = A[i] / 10000;
                A[i] = A[i] % 10000;
                A[i + 1] += more;

                //if new digit should be opened
                if (i + 1 > current4Digit)
                {
                    current4Digit++;
                }

            }


        }
    }

    //getting data from array to generate answer
    string answer = "";

    for (int i = current4Digit; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        answer += A[i].ToString() + ",";
    }

    return answer;
}
```

The problem I have is that it doesn't display correctly the number, which contains 0 in reality. for example 2 ^ (50) = 1 125 899 906 842 624 and with my algorithm I get 1 125 899 96 842 624 (0 is missing). This isn't only for 50...

This happens when I have the following situation for example:

[image]

How I can make this algorithm better?

Comment: You could pad the left of the strings with the `0` character if needed (the [`PadLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx) method takes the total required characters and the character to use for padding if the string needs to be lengthened). For example: `answer += A[i].ToString().PadLeft(4, '0') + ",";` And then you can use [`TrimStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove any leading zeros from the result: `return answer.TrimStart('0');`

Comment: Yes, but it will make more complex the code? won't it?

Comment: I don't think so? It doesn't add any more lines of code or any more logic, just another method call that returns a string.

Comment: You are right, it works, but I think maybe the algorithm needs improvement..

Comment: Your answer solved the problem I had...

Comment: I am also interested in, if I had implemented this algorithm well..

Comment: For that kind of question, you should post to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, I know... They say that the code posted there should work, so first, I posted it here. now I will take it there... Post your answer below and I will mark it as right answer...

Comment: To be clear, you are attempting to calculate 2 to the n *and render it in base ten*, right?  Because I gotta tell you, this problem is a lot easier if you render it in binary. :-)

Comment: @LOG: You say it makes the code *more complex*, so ask yourself how to make it *less complex*. Follow this plan: first, make it compile. Then make it correct. Then make it elegant.  Don't try to make it elegant before it is correct! You'll have a lovely wrong program.

Comment: Essentially what you are doing here is converting the number to base 10000, which is then easy to convert to base 10. You have 32 bits in an int, so you could go bigger. You could solve the problem in base 100000000, for instance, without any additional difficulty, and you'd use far fewer integers.

Comment: Or use longs, and go up to base 1000000000000000000.

Comment: (Without support for integers with at least [60 bits](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDC_6600) without sign, choosing base 10000 simplifies implementation of multiplication, division and square-root. On machines with decent support, [packed BCD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) is an alternative using no more space - useful for printing [Ackermann(4, 2)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Definition_and_properties) from a 16KBytes [8080](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8080) "intelligent terminal".)

Comment: @greybeard: That's a great point. In my answer to this question on code review, I give the challenge of implementing multiplication and division and yes, it does get somewhat easier if you have access to 64 bit longs to do the "real" arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to resolve this is to pad your 4-digit numbers with leading zeroes if they are less than four digits by using the [`PadLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
answer += A[i].ToString().PadLeft(4, '0') + ",";
```

And then you can use the [`TrimStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx) method to remove any leading zeros from the final result:

```
return answer.TrimStart('0');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `BigInteger`, which is already included in .Net Core or available in the [System.Runtime.Numerics Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Numerics/4.3.0).

```
static string Efficient(int power)
{
    var result = BigInteger.Pow(2, power);
    return result.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

On my machine, `NotEfficient` takes roughly 80ms, where `Efficient` takes 0.3ms. You should be able to manipulate that string (if I'm understanding your problem statement correctly):

```
static string InsertCommas(string value)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(value);

    for (var i = value.Length - 4; i > 0; i -= 4)
    {
        sb.Insert(i, ',');
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: i'd change the Pow into left shift